How can I make a 2D FTL-lane map on a galaxy-wide scale?
I want to finally get around to actually making a map for my Sci Fi worldbuilding project I have been slowly working on for the last few years. For context, this setting takes place in the Milky Way and is heavily inspired on the game Stellaris.
I have been looking online for tools to help me with this, but many of them are either grid based or 3D. I could always just start drawing a network myself on a image of the Milky Way. However, drawing over a 1000 systems and the FLT lanes connecting them would make me go insane.
So can anybody help me with this? I would already be happy if I could just find something that can generate a network, which I can just overlay on a galaxy image. It just needs to be rougly circular, with a distinction between systems and FTL lanes.
If anyone has a another idea on how to do this, I am open to suggestions.
Edit: Some aditional information,

I do not care if the network doesn't overlap with the actual star systems of the Milky Way. I never laid down actual system locations exactly because I didn't have a map
I have some experience with programming, but that taught me more that I am very bad at it. I can do some basic stuff if there's a guide for it, but otherwise I am out of luck

Edit 2: Some answers for questions

I am aware of the galaxy having bilions of stars. However, with the worldbuilding being based of Stellaris, the actual number of the systems you can travel to would be around 1000 to 2000 systems
This is not for a game, so it doesn't have to be an interactive map

(Picture below shows a galaxy map from Stellaris with the hyperlane network)


I believe this question might be better on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com They will probably be able to give better advice about how to implement this using your exact programming stack.

While waiting for answers, take a peek at our List of Worldbuilding Resources. Maybe you'll find something there you've not evaluated that can help.

Count of stars is much, much more in our galaxy, maybe 10 or 100billions.

Could you state if it's for a game (maybe requiring multiple levels of resolution of connectivity) or a fixed image for a book/tabletop-game - how you want to use it would seem to alter potential answers - and maybe make it suitable (or not) for our [gamedev.se] site.

For a worldbuilding project you can always just start with the sections of the map you actually need, and expand as-needed, when-needed.  Even thousands of systems won't be that terrible if done a couple dozen at a time when it becomes relevant to whatever other piece of it you're working on.

Why do you need 'FTL Lanes'?  What's wrong with just pointing at your destination and engaging ludicrous speed?

Your screenshot from Stellaris looks very nice. Why not use that one? Or, if you need slightly different parameters (different galaxy shape, different density of hyperlanes), change the settings in Stellaris and generate a new one.
You can tweak it after the fact to add specific points of interest that you want. Draw in Sol System and any other named stars that are important to your story.

The Delaunay triangulation algorithm is a representative method for drawing non-intersecting nodes for a prepared set of point clouds. The hyperlanes in Stellaris also appear to be connected using this method.
However, to make the appearance more natural, they likely applied the following post-processing steps:

Remove edges with long distances
Probabilistically delete edges
Remove nodes without edges

If necessary, try looking for a tool to visualize Delaunay diagrams.
If you want to create something more detailed, I recommend learning a programming language and drawing graphs. The following diagram was drawn using the SciPy, Matplotlib library with Python.


That system at -2,-1 is going to be busy.

By nodes i think you mean what are more typically called edges; to me, a node is a vertex.

@AntonSherwood Thank you for pointing that out. It was a basic mistake.

@perkins So is the one at 1, -2 -- if you control those two systems and fortify them you seal off the entire inner ring of the spiral.

@Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI And there's one that's at roughly 2.75, 0.25 that controls the short path from the heavily-interconnected cluster to the northern rim. Close to 20x as far going the other way around.

You won't find any read-made packages for a realistic approximation. The closest you'll find is a map of the stars nearest to Earth. 3d settings aren't conducive to game play. Overall, the 3d cognitive processes on your average gamer are better than most, but you'd lose most of your audience by insisting on it.
But you aren't designing a game. There have been several efforts in this direction, for instance:
https://www.illustris-project.org/
https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/10661/
https://beltoforion.de/en/spiral_galaxy_renderer/spiral-galaxy-renderer.html
Your approach to this will be dictated by your dedication to realism. You could just take @peacock59's solution and call it good. Every step beyond that is going to require more programming. Here are the challenges you'd have to surmount.

Plotting a realistic 3d map of stars in your galaxy would be a super-computer level task. You could reduce that to inhabitable worlds, but that's still at least a million. You'd need to place those stars based on an approximation of the 3d density of a real galaxy, then delete any that are unrealistically close to each other, and specify the size of the stars.

Initial identification of possible routes. This involves calculating which stars are closest to each other.  The brute force method would produce a solution set of a trillion or so possibilities. You can discard lanes over an unsurvivable distance, but remember that the gap between spiral arms is similar to the width across spiral arms. Does your FTL method prevent passing through nebula? If so, you can plot nebula and delete those links. Sort all of the remaining routes.

Mark a connection between all of the closest stars until you start getting stars with multiple connections. From there, you want to avoid connecting stars where a two-hop solution can be performed in, I dunno, 1/sqrt(3) distance. You be the judge.

Mapping a 3d space onto a 2d space either requires color or intensity. I would recommend drawing the map (viewed from the north) with purple stars to the galactic north and red stars in the galactic south. Color the spaceways that way, too. Draw longer spaceways with a lower brightness so that the shorter ones are easier to spot.


I've considered this a few times, but it's a bit more than just a side project.

Found a way to do it, inspired by Christopher Wells answer, but with a few aditions.

Install mod for Stellaris to increase galaxy size (Used 'Yet Another Galaxy Enhancement Mod', set system count to 5000)
Load up a new save, disable empire spawns (to decrease already long loading time)
Destroy your empire with console commands (may be unnecessary)
Install StellarMaps (Open source application for creating maps of your stellaris saves)
Load up save file created in step 2

You can then use StellarMaps features to get a map of the (empty) galaxy

Nice! Do you have an approximation of how may systems it generated?
